# How to diagnose EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) crash in iPad iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash

I am getting a crash with an iPad app that is (at least to me) non-specific.  It's an Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT.  I am thinking a double memory release or attempting to access a released variable but I hoping someone can shed more light as I hunt through the code.  The full crash log is:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000102, 0x31ccebd0
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                 0x0000ab96 CFRelease + 90
1   CoreFoundation                 0x0005209e __CFRunLoopTimerDeallocate + 18
2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000ac68 _CFRelease + 160
3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000ab8e CFRelease + 82
4   CoreFoundation                 0x00019130 __CFTypeCollectionRelease + 8
5   CoreFoundation                 0x00019962 __CFArrayReleaseValues + 302
6   CoreFoundation                 0x0001982c __CFArrayDeallocate + 8
7   CoreFoundation                 0x0000ac68 _CFRelease + 160
8   CoreFoundation                 0x0000ab8e CFRelease + 82
9   CoreFoundation                 0x000279c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1092
10  CoreFoundation                 0x0002748c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
11  CoreFoundation                 0x00027394 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
12  GraphicsServices               0x000044a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
13  GraphicsServices               0x00004550 GSEventRun + 56
14  UIKit                          0x000374ce -[UIApplication _run] + 406
15  UIKit                          0x00035148 UIApplicationMain + 664
16  MultipleDetailViews            0x00002ccc main (main.m:55)
17  MultipleDetailViews            0x00002c80 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0002d974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x000d7704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x000d7174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x000d6b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0007b24a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00073970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00001268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00003354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00027e54 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                 0x000276de __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0002748c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                 0x00027394 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                        0x000060c8 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0007a886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0006fa88 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00001268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00003354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00027e54 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                 0x000276de __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0002748c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                 0x00027394 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                     0x0002d5f6    +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                     0x0000b192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                     0x00004242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0007a886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib              0x0006fa88 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0002568c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                 0x0005ee72 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0007a886 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0006fa88 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x2fdff994      r2: 0x3e56e898      r3: 0x00000118
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x001eb094      r6: 0x0000002c      r7: 0x2fdfec04
    r8: 0x001eb090    r9: 0x001fc098     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x3e58f038    sp: 0x2fdfebfc      lr: 0x31d160a5      pc: 0x31cceb96
  cpsr: 0x600f0030
```

Comment: Did you try a "Clean All" and a rebuild from scratch? I find that a lot of these mysterious crashes happen because of the build system not rebuilding things when it should. you might also want to just delete your build directory and rebuild from scratch just to make sure.

Comment: Did you have NSZombeEnabled set to YES? Enable that, run a static analyzer and use breakpoints to step through your code. This should definitely shed more light on the situation. Do it, and post an update here. With the info maybe we can solve this....

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error too and fixed it. This person is running OS3 most likely and you are using a code block from OS4 you need to set a weak link on the library so that it can properly load. in your build settings for LLVM -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib